# Android Studio/Intellii: Location of project configuration file

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I've marked certain directories & files as excluded in Android studio. I'm looking for the file where intellij/Android Studio keeps track of those configurations.
It used to be inside the .iml file however I don't see that file in my project or new projects anymore. I couldn't find this info in files under .idea directory either.

Does someone know where can I find this configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

This information is stored in .uml file of the module. See

[image]

Comment: I dont have the iml file